# Mysql MIN() Max() function with JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

i have a problem, i need to find MIN() and MAX() with JOIN and GROUP BY with Mysql.

I have 3 tables :

- Parent(parent_id)
- Child(child_id, parent_id)
- Price(price_id, child_id, price)

One parent can have many childs, and a child has only one price.

Here is my query to get all prices of a Parent:

```
select   child.parent_id ,  price.child_id  , price.price
from parent 
 inner join  child on child.parent_id = parent.id 
 inner join price on price.child_id = child.id
```

I want to find the min price of a Parent. But i don't want only the price, i want the price_id !

Can you help me to make this query to find the price_id of the min() price of each parent ?

Here are data samples :

```
parent1 : parent_id=1
parent2 : parent_id=2

child1 : child_id=1 , parent_id=1
child2 : child_id=2 , parent_id=1
child3 : child_id=3 , parent_id=1

child4 : child_id=4 , parent_id=2
child5 : child_id=5 , parent_id=2
child6 : child_id=6 , parent_id=2

price1 : price_id=1 , child_id=1, price=15
price2 : price_id=2 , child_id=2, price=5
price3 : price_id=3 , child_id=3, price=10

price4 : price_id=4 , child_id=4, price=10
price5 : price_id=5 , child_id=5, price=20
price6 : price_id=6 , child_id=6, price=30
```

I want to find for parent1 the id of the min price of his childs, the result is : price_id=2

I want to find for parent2 the id of the min price of his childs, the result is : price_id=4

I want to find for parent1 the id of the MAX price of his childs, the result is : price_id=1

I want to find for parent2 the id of the MAX price of his childs, the result is : price_id=6

Thank you !

Comment: update your question and add  a proper  data sample and the expectedx result

Comment: .. i don't see data sample ..

Comment: i edited ma question with data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  some cinner join on selected  table

```
  select distinct  t.parent_id, price.price_id
  from price 
  inner join child on price.child_id = child.child_id
  inner join (
      select   
      parent.parent_id
      min(price) min_price
    from parent 
    inner join child on parent.parent_id = child.parent_id
    inner join price on price.child_id = child.child_id
    group by parent.parent_id ) t on t.min_price = price.price 
            and t.parent_id = child.parent_id
```

and looking to your result

then group by the result

```
    select parent_id, min(price_id), price from ( 
    select distinct  t.parent_id, price.price_id, price.price
      from price 
      inner join child on price.child_id = child.child_id
      inner join (
          select   
          parent.parent_id
          min(price) min_price
        from parent 
        inner join child on parent.parent_id = child.parent_id
        inner join price on price.child_id = child.child_id
        group by parent.parent_id ) t on t.min_price = price.price 
                and t.parent_id = child.parent_id

    ) t 
    group by arent_id, price
```

Comment: your query doesn't return only one price if a parent has many childs with same min price  :(
I need one result only even there is many prices with same min price.

Comment: sorry it doesn't work, it retrieves all price_id with same price , not only one :(

Comment: show a sample of the result  .yiu have  .. . i can't understand  .. without a proper sample  ..

Comment: parent_id price_id price
 831 5462 999 
 831 5471 999
 831 5474 999
 831 5479 999
 831 5488 999 

I want only first line. I want only one min price_id for all my parents , if many same min prices, i want first for example, with a limit 1 but where to put it ?

Comment: youn should update you question and add the sample  ..in comment the data are not clear